# username regex alphanumeric with underscore only

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to find a regex expression for php's preg_match that allows alphanumeric characters, with underscores, but the underscore MUST be between characters (not on beginning or end of string), and there can never be 2 underscores next to each other.

Examples:

INVALID:

```
_name
na_me_
na__me
```

VALID:

```
na_me
na_m_e
```

The one i've found works for most parts of this, but doesn't protect against repeated underscores is:

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
```

But like I said, that still allows for cases like na__me.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: @John McMullen What's not fine? Yours does not allow `na__me`

Comment: English, sorry to not specify
@Jonny5 , i want it to prohibit the na__me.. the one i listed allows it (basically, only find na_me, and not na__me)

Comment: @JohnMcMullen When I test yours, it seems to disallow repeated underscores.  See http://regex101.com/r/bX4wW8  The only one's matching are the one's you show flagged as valid

Comment: odd, when i tried it again on a second server, as well as the regex101 check site, it works properly...i guess this was all for null...

Answer (score 5):

This will do it:

```
(?x)           # enable comments and whitespace to make
               # it understandable.  always always do this.

^              # front anchor

[\pL\pN]       # an alphanumeric

# now begin a repeat group that 
# will go through the end of the string

(?: [\pL\pN]   # then either another alnum
  |            # or else an underbar surrounded
               # by an alnum to either side of it
    (?<= [\pL\pN] )      # must follow an alnum behind it
    _                    # the real underscore
    (?=  [\pL\pN] )      # and must precede an alnum before it
) *            # repeat that whole group 0 or more times

\z             # through the true end of the string
```

So you start off with an alphanumeric, then have any number of alphanumunders through the end, constraining any actual underscores to be surround by an actual alphanumerics to either side.

Answer (score 1):

Yours looks fine. As does this one, which is a bit shorter:

```
/^[a-z](?:_?[a-z0-9])*$/i
```

Comment: @VahidAlvandi `\.` matches a dot. Need the backslash because `.` has special meaning; without the backslash it matches _any_ character. Inside a character class, `.` loses its special meaning, so there the backslash is not required. For example, `[0-9.]` matches a digit or dot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want REGEX to handle a specific length of characters, you use `{` and `}`

ex.

`[a-z]{2,4}`

Will return all strings of lowercase letters of length 2, 3, and 4.

In your case you would use `{0,1}` to signify that `NO` or `1` underscores are acceptable.